# In my CentOS7.2, I have the `python3` command, but why I can not use pyvenv?

Tags: python, pyvenv

In my CentOS7.2, I have the `python3` command, but why I can not use pyvenv?

```
[root@www myProject]# pyvenv --version
-bash: pyvenv: there is no command
[root@www myProject]# python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
[root@www myProject]# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Also, did you check for `pyvenv3`, `pyvenv3.5`, and `pyvenv-3.5`? (There's obviously no need to disambiguate `pyvenv3` and `pyvenv2`, but a distro might choose to follow the unambiguous naming pattern anyway, to avoid confusion with, e.g., `pyvenv` running 3.5 and `pip` running 2.7.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pyvenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) was deprecated in 3.6, in favor of using `python3 -m venv`.

You may wonder what this has to do with your Python 3.5.2, since 3.5 < 3.6. Well, if you run a Python 3.5—or even 3.6—installer from python.org, or `make install` from source, you will get a `pyvenv` command (and possibly also `pyvenv3`, `pyvenv3.5`, and/or `pyvenv-3.5`). But you didn't do that; you used your distro's Python 3.5.

Distros have a long tradition of breaking up large packages like Python into a core package and various "optional" packages like `python3-pip` or `python3-curses`. And not just Red Hat;<sup>1</sup> Debian and Ubuntu also separate `venv` out into a `python3-venv` package. How they decide what's "core" and what's "optional" is a complicated process, with a lot of legacy concerns, so I don't know exactly what the reasons are, but I can speculate.

First, most linux users seem to prefer using `pipenv` and/or `virtualenv`. They have more features, they aren't stuck with Python's glacial release cycle, and you can use the same version with Python 3.4, 3.6, and even 2.7. In 2011, [adding `venv` seemed like TOOWTDI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/) to eliminate the incompatible competing virtual environment solutions, but what's happened instead is that they've become compatible with each other while `venv` has stagnated. In fact, the official Python Packaging Authority<sup>2</sup> recommends [`virtualenv` for installing packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/)  and [`pipenv` for developing applications](https://packaging.python.org/guides/tool-recommendations/#application-dependency-management), and [the PyPA rejected a suggestion to change that in 2017](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/15).

Also, as the 3.6 docs explain, the reason `pyvenv` was deprecated was basically because of the confusion it causes on Linux distros that ship multiple versions of Python.

And finally: `venv` depends on `pip`. Which isn't built in. How does that work? Well, if you get a python.org binary installer, it will include `pip`. And if you build it from source, Python (3.4+) uses [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) to bootstrap `pip` and `setuptools`. But that's primarily for the convenience of Mac and Windows users, and people who build custom versions of Python; few linux distros rely on `ensurepip`. After all, the reason you're using an enterprisey stable distro is that you want specific, tested versions of everything, which you do by installing their `python3-pip` package, not by getting a kludgy `pip` out of `ensurepip` and then doing `pip install --upgrade pip` to get some future version they haven't tested. So, unless a distro is going to merge their `pip` into their `python` package, it doesn't make much sense to include `venv`.

---

<sub>1. CentOS 7.2 of course just copies RHEL 7.2, because that's the point of CentOS, so the question is why RHEL 7.2 made `venv` an optional package.</sub>

<sub>2. Just how official is PyPA? It's not entirely clear—it's under the PSF, and uses a python.org SIG, but it maintains a separate presence. But if you look at the names involved, it's largely the same people who are both Python core devs and developers for the major linux distros. So, it's not too surprising those distros pay attention to PyPA—it's the same people making the decisions in both places.</sub>